# Windows explorer doesn't open My Documents, Music or anything when clicking the library?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I recently installed Windows 7, and for some reason my Libraries don't open to `My Documents`, `Music` and so on.. I can access my files by typing into the explorers address bar, but clicking anything doesn't do anything, it just stays on the same screen. What's wrong?

Since this is occurring on a relatively new install, I currently have `259GB` free out of `297GB` on my HD. The My Documents folder only has about 500 mb of Data.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't do anything` - What happens when you double click on it ? Does it stays on same screen ? Or the issue is about the content in those libraries ?

Comment: It stays on the same screen. Nothing opens.

Comment: What about folders, does clicking on folders act as expected ?

Comment: Well, if I click on a folder it takes me inside, but clicking on that library like homepage doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you able to go inside library from the pane located at the Left side of explorer window ?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Try resetting explorer settings, using `Restore Defaults`. Access from Organize > Folder and Search Options.

Comment: @Lamb, didn't work.

Comment: Let's try to be a little more specific.  If you open Computer and then double-click on C:, does the C: drive open up?  With the C: drive open, if you double-click on "Program Files" in the right-hand pane, does the Program Files directory open up?  Does double-clicking on Desktop icons cause them to open normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

1. Right-click and delete each library (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos etc.)
2. Right-click **Libraries** in Windows Explorer's left pane and click on **Restore default libraries**
3. Test if the library locations work fine; if they do, re-add any custom library locations

---

## 2

Try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated Command Prompt (`Start / Type "cmd" (without quotes) / Right-click cmd.exe / Run as administrator`).

---

## 3

1. Create a new user account/profile
2. See if libraries work fine; if they do, [copy over your files from the old corrupted profile](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Fix-a-corrupted-user-profile)

---

## 4

1. Make sure [hidden files and folders are visible](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/)
2. Navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries` in Windows Explorer and expand Libraries in the left pane
3. Select the first library (for example, Documents) listed in the left pane
4. Right-click and select **Properties**
5. Go to the **Security** tab and see if your user name is listed at the top under **Group or user names**, and whether there is a check-mark against **Allow Full control** under **Permissions** below
6. If not, click on **Edit**
7. Click on **Add**
8. In the **object names** input area, enter your user name and click **Check Names**, then click OK once found and validated
9. Click on your user name in the top list of **Group or user names**
10. Select the **Allow Full control** check-box under **Permissions**, then click on **Apply**
11. Repeat steps 4-10 for each library

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work.

Comment: @Link: So in the left pane if you click on any library, what do you see in the right pane?

Comment: Nothing changes. Just whatever screen I was intially on.

Comment: @Link: Ok, so solution #1 did not work. Can you try #2-4 in turn and report back with the results?

Comment: Hmm, that worked!, but I've disabled libraries, they're not crucial.

Comment: @Link: Just for the record, which of #2-4 worked? As for not using them, yeah, I don't either. My own organization system is *far* superior. :)

Comment: #3, just profile was corrupted.

Comment: @Link: Ah, well, good to know what exactly was causing this.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the XML files I mentioned in my answer were actually corrupted. Did you actually check them, as I suggested? By opening them in a text editor?

Comment: I did, however I didn't actually see anything different, it might have been some other data that affected the libraries though.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem after latest windows patch. I installed Windows folder fix and it works.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/windows_file_and_folder_diag/en-us

This is a link to a Microsoft Fixit wizard designed to automatically diagnose and repair problems with files and folders in Windows, like deleting files or folders from the recycle bin, or trying to copy, move, rename or delete a file.

> **What it fixes**
>
> - You cannot empty the Recycle Bin or delete a file or a folder inside the Recycle Bin.
> - When you try to rename or move a file, you receive the following error message: "The file or folder does not exist."
> - When you copy, move, rename, or delete a file on a network share, you receive the following error message: "There is a network or file permission error. The network connection may be lost" or "The folder does not exist. The file may have been moved or deleted. Do you want to create it?"
> - Your View settings or customizations for one or more folders may be lost or incorrect.
> - You cannot use keyboard shortcuts to select more than one item in Windows Explorer, or you cannot select multiple items in a Windows Explorer window by holding the SHIFT key or the CTRL key while you click the items.
> - Some icons in My Computer, in Windows Explorer, on the desktop, or on the Quick Launch Bar change randomly.
>
> **Runs on**
>
> - Microsoft Windows XP
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Vista
> - Windows 8

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  In a case like this, where the link is to a utility, provide at least a description of what's on the other end of the link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds almost like your system is hanging do to long load times, this could be caused by having to many files in the folders/on the drive for your hardware to process quickly enough to open the folder.

Could you state your system specs and if possible space left on your disk and total space?

Comment: reflected question for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your library settings aren't generating properly? Others have suggested resetting to defaults through the Windows GUI, but it could be that something is preventing that step from completing successfully.

Trying resetting to default again, and then check the Event Manager snap-in. Look under System or Applications and see if any errors that may be related are shown.

If that doesn't shed any light, try going to this path in Explorer:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`

Your libraries will be listed in this folder. Double-clicking on them should open the library. If you right-click, though, you can open the file in a text editor (I was able to open them in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) using the *Edit with Notepad++...* context menu entry it can install with), and you'll notice that they're simply XML files. You should, at the least, be able to check that the XML syntax is correct by eyeballing it. They should look similar to the example shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798389(v=vs.85).aspx#libraryms_example

If Windows is generating corrupted XML files (assuming your attempts to reset to default as others have suggested didn't fix it), I would suppose that you have bad sectors on your hard drive and those files are getting partially (or wholly) stored on them. Try running scandisk and seeing if it detects anything. If it does, it should mark those sectors as bad, and cause Windows to try and recover those files elsewhere, or at least the next time you regenerate them they'll be stored elsewhere on the disk.

Comment: Well, went to the path, but that didn't help either. I'll try scandisk now then.

Comment: @Link What didn't help? Double-clicking them there didn't work? Makes sense. Did you try viewing the files in a text editor and seeing if they looked corrupt? Regardless, scandisk should help if it indeed is an issue.

Comment: Hmm, ran scandisk,, nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the folders manually to the libraries - click on a library, "Add folder to a library" and choose your music or documents or any other directory. Repeat for every library needed.

Answer (score -2):

Exactly the same thing happened to me, but I discovered that it was the user accounts settings that was corrupt. just go to user accounts and create a new user account, then give it full administrative rights. Delete your current user profile. It would ask if you would like to backup all your documents, pictures, etc. from the previous account into a folder on the new account, agree to that, then delete the corrupt account. Ensure everything is working perfectly in your new account, restart your PC, then rename the new user account back to the same name you used for the previous one. You can then copy and paste your backed up stuff to their various locations. Everything will be perfect and you won't need to tamper with ur registry files or stuff like that. All your programs installed will not be affected in anyway and everything will work perfectly.