# Explorer Won't Open Music Directory

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, music

Windows 8.1

Hello,

I'm trying to open my Music folder in Explorer, so I can go through and delete a few songs.

I have about 122 songs in the directory now, plus two folders. I can Save files to the directory, and Windows Media Player plays the songs & the playlist without any problems.

But when I try to open in Explorer, it hangs for hours and just shows this:
[image]

It just hangs there, and I get a blinking "This Folder is Empty" message where my songs should be.

How can I fix this, and get my files to show?

EDIT:

Strange, explorer won't show my files but the "Save As" dialog box shows 'em just fine...
[image]

Comment: Have you tried going directly to the folder location of your music instead of going to the library view?

Comment: What have you tired so far? A Reboot?  Disk checks?  Can you properly access each of the folders that belong to your Music Library in Explorer?  How about via the command-line?

Comment: can you navigate to the **real** music folder, i.e. C:\Users\ _your user name_ \Music and see the files there ?

Comment: Shinjijai - Look at the screenshots. That's Explorer, not the library view. Techie007 - Command-line, yes. Reboot, yes. Disk check yes. MAKZ - Yes, I can see the whole directory by going through the REAL folder. Wonder if I should somehow delete the shortcut (somehow) and remap it?

Comment: Go over the suggestions in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/482065/23133 and let us know the results.

Comment: This PC > Music is the library and not the real location of your music. As @MAKZ suggeste, take a look at C:\Users\Music\ or anywhere else your have set in your library to scan your music.

Comment: I cannot say this is a solution, but if the problem is still there  just give this **crazy** idea a try : copy the contents of c:\..\music to any other folder xyz, delete the Music folder. Now again create a new folder with name _Music_ and right_click->Properties->Customize and make sure it is optimized for music. Now copy back the contents that you copied earlier. it is almost like _remapping_